# Beginner Scheme: Turning Binary Search Trees into lists

Tags: scheme, racket

I am having trouble with binary search trees and turning them into lists.

```
(define-struct node (key val left right))
;; A binary search tree (bst) is either
;; empty, or
;; a structure (make-node k v l r), where
;; k is a number (the key),
;; v is a string (the value),
;; l is a bst, where every key in l is less than k, and
;; r is a bst, where every key in r is greater than k.
```

Can anybody give me hints on how to approach this question?

Create a function bst that consumes a binary search tree and returns a list of all the strings in the value field of the binary search tree nodes and the list must be in descending order based on the key values in the binary search tree.

```
;;Examples: (bst (make-node 4 "James" (make-node 2 "Kien" empty empty)
;;(make-node 5 "Jack" empty (make-node 11 "Cole" empty empty)))) => (list "Cole" "Jack" "James" "Kien")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried applying the design recipe that your teacher is talking about?  Every question you've asked on SO seems to be of the form "I got this problem..." but where you have not shown any of the steps that you would have done with the Design Recipe in hand.  You _do_ understand that the primary content being taught in a Program-by-Design class is *design*, and not the coding, right?  Please try it!  The questions you're asking are frankly showing a lack of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have to visit all the nodes in the tree using a reverse [in-orden traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order) (right subtree / value / left subtree), while at the same time creating a list with the answer. Something along these lines:

```
(define (tree->list tree)
  (if (empty? tree)
      empty
      (append (tree->list (node-right tree))
              (cons (node-val tree)
                    (tree->list (node-left tree))))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(define bst
  (make-node 4 "James"
             (make-node 2 "Kien" empty empty)
             (make-node 5 "Jack" empty
                        (make-node 11 "Cole" empty empty))))

(tree->list bst)
=> (list "Cole" "Jack" "James" "Kien")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (tree->list tree)
  (if(leaf? tree)
     (list (node tree))
     (cond((right-branch-only? tree)(append (list(node tree))
                                            (tree->list (right-branch tree))))
          ((left-branch-only? tree)(append (list(node tree))
                                           (tree->list (left-branch tree))))
          (else(append (list (node tree))
                       (append (tree->list (left-branch tree))
                               (tree->list (right-branch tree))))))))
```